Derivation of Rutherford scattering formula in Landau & Lifshitz mechanics book

This is from Landau & Lifshitz Mechanics book, p.49, the scattering formula (18.4) for general elastic scattering that gives the scattering angle

On p.53 this formula is given, where just the inverse potential is plugged into (18.4) and "elementary integration" is used. How did Landau arrived at this integral? Which elementary integration did he use? No other textbook that I have consulted derives the Rutherford formula like that.

While I love Landau and Lifshitz, the reality is Landau was a genius and things that were obvious to him aren’t all that obvious to anyone else.

@JonCuster yes, Landau's genius can make it brutal for students to follow, but considering that it is a text for graduates, who should have dealt with similar integrals and their substitutions everywhere else e.g. in Goldstein, this isn't that bad of a leap of logic. There are so many other instances where it would be way worse.

Hi Fortinbras. Are you mainly asking about eq. (18.4) or eq. (19.1)?

(19.1). How to get from (18.4) to (19.1).

If you put the potential in the (18.4) formula, you have
$$
\phi_0 = \int_{r_{min}}^{\infty} {\rho/r^2 \, dr \over \sqrt{1-(\rho/r)^2-(2\alpha/mv_\infty^2 r)}}
$$
One evident substitution is $u=\rho/r$. If you do this substitution, you have $du = - \rho/r^2 dr$ and
$$
\phi_0 = \int_0^{\rho/r_{min}} {du\over \sqrt{1-u^2 - ku}}
$$
where $k= 2\alpha/mv_\infty^2\rho$. If this integral is trivial or not is a matter of opinion, but you can find it in tables of integrals for sure. The next suggestive step is to complete squares and put it in the form
$$
\phi_0 = \int_0^{\rho/r_{min}} {du\over \sqrt{(1+k^2/4)-(u+k/2)^2}}
$$
I'll let the rest of the fun for you.
EDIT: Since you had problem solving the integral, let's solve it. First, fixing my mistake in the choice of the constant, we have
$$
\phi_0 = \int_0^{\rho/r_{min}} {du\over \sqrt{(1+k^2)-(u+k)^2}}
$$
where $k=\alpha/mv_\infty^2\rho$. The good change of variables in integrals like that is $x ={(u+k)\over \sqrt{1+k^2}}$. I'll ignore the limits of integration and just back to variable $u$ in the final. With this change
$$
\phi_0 = \int {dx\over \sqrt{1-x^2}} = -\cos^{-1}(x)
$$
This integral above is elementar, but you can see that it results in $-\cos^{-1}(x)$ either by differentiating the function or doing the substitution $x = \cos(\theta)$. Now, back in the $u$ variable
$$
\phi_0 = -\cos^{-1}\left ({u + k \over \sqrt{1+k^2}}\right)\Bigg\rvert_{0}^{\rho/r_{min}} = -\cos^{-1}\left ({\rho/r_{min} + k \over \sqrt{1+k^2}}\right) + \cos^{-1}\left ( {k \over \sqrt{1+k^2}}\right)
$$
Now, you see that the angle $\phi_0$ is given by the difference between two angles, the first one is the angle associated to $r_{min}$. We can choose the reference so the first angle vanishes, i.e.
$$
\cos^{-1}\left ({\rho/r_{min} + k \over \sqrt{1+k^2}}\right) = 0
$$
and it let us with the expression
$$
\phi_0 = \cos^{-1}\left ( {\alpha/mv_\infty^2\rho \over \sqrt{1+(\alpha/mv_\infty^2\rho)^2}}\right)
$$

This is correct, but you missed the niceness of picking k to be half what you chose, so that those pesky quarters and halves will disappear, leaving you with something that fits Landau's result easier.

thanks. Unfortunately, the rest is not so fun. I found the integral from a table and plugged everything back in, but an unwanted p/r term appears in the numerator. I guess the integration limits take care of that, but how? I also asked after an hour trying all the LLMs. They just gave me nonsense..
